# Cascade Delete doesn't work in Asp.net 5 and EF Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to delete `User` from database, `User` has its own `Recipes`. Cascade delete doesn't work even though I configured it in model builder.

The error I'm getting is:

> SqlException: The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_Recipes_AspNetUsers_ApplicationUserId". The conflict occurred in database "master", table "dbo.Recipes", column 'ApplicationUserId'.

**AplicationUser.cs** :

```
namespace WebApplication.Models
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public ICollection<Recipe> Recipes { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Recipe.cs**

```
namespace WebApplication.Models
{
    public class Recipe
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string RecipeName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string RecipeContent { get; set; }
        public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
        public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**ApplicationDbContext.cs**

```
namespace WebApplication.Models
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasMany(e => e.Recipes).WithOne(e => e.ApplicationUser)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientCascade);


        }

        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Recipe> Recipes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**UserController.cs**

```
public IActionResult Delete(string id)
{
    var user = _applicationDbContext.Users
                                    .Where(u => u.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
    return View(user);
}
      
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Delete(ApplicationUser appuser)
{
    var user = _applicationDbContext.Users
                                    .Where(u => u.Id == appuser.Id).FirstOrDefault();
    _applicationDbContext.Users.Remove(user);
    _applicationDbContext.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

I've been looking for solution to that for like an hour and nothing works.

Configuring modulbuilder seems to be solution for almost everyone but certainly doesn't work for me.

Comment: Have you always had the cascade delete behaviour configured? Or did you add it recently? If you have made the change recently, have you remembered to add a migration and apply it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ClientCascade` will only delete related entities that are tracked by the DbContext, where-as `Cascade` will also set up a Delete Orphans on the FK Constraint in the database if EF is set up to manage the schema.

You will need to ensure hte DbContext is tracking the related entities for them to be deleted:

```
var user = _applicationDbContext.Users
    .Include(x => x.Recipies)
    .Where(u => u.Id == appuser.Id)
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

This ensures the DbContext is aware of the related entities and should delete those prior to the user being deleted. You also need to be aware of any other entity that might have a reference to a User record or FK. For instance if other records are tracking something like a CreatedBy then these will likely be set up to have FKs back to User. Relying on `ClientCascade` can be problematic here, and Cascade Deletes may not be desirable, opting for a Soft-Delete model instead. (I.e. `IsActive` flag on ApplicationUser rather than Deleting the row)

Also, avoid using the `First` methods unless you are expecting multiple rows and specifically want the first one. These methods should also only ever be used in combination with `OrderBy` methods. If you expect 1 row, use `Single`. If you expect 0 or 1 row, use `SingleOrDefault`. This helps ensure that any unexpected data state results in a meaningful exception rather than silently doing something unexpected.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix that by changing this line: var user = _applicationDbContext.Users.Where(u => u.Id == appuser.Id).FirstOrDefault();
to this:  var user = _userManager.Users.Include(e=>e.Recipes).Where(u => u.Id == appuser.Id).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: Saw an answer pop up just as I was finishing off my own. :) Yes, ClientCascase only deletes tracked references, so you have to eager-load any related entities to ensure the DbContext can delete them.